# How to Fix DNS Leak with VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

So Im using Juno and I can't get my NordVPN to work correctly. I keep getting DNS Leaks. I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the OpenVPN protocol. Anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi This is a bug in openVPN. If you want to fix DNS leak you need to use Nordvpn linux client. You can connect to nordvpn with terminal command `nordvpn connect <server name>` after installing the nordvpn client. See website of nordvpn how to install on linux.